# How to change required field error message?

Tags: 2013, list-form, validation, newform

I have two required columns in a custom list. When adding an item using OOTB new form, the required field validator shows same error message

> You can't leave this blank.

For both required columns. Does anybody know what is the best way to show different messages for each of them?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Required Field. Just add a validation based on following formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Field]),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Now use Validation Error Message for custom message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Strings.STS to override message. Just add this code to your page or master page if you want to apply all your site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            try {
                if (Strings.STS.L_SPClientRequiredValidatorError != null) {
                    Strings.STS.L_SPClientRequiredValidatorError = "What ever you want!";
                }
            }
            catch (exception) { }
        });
    </script>
```

For more information:

SharePoint 2010 use message:

> "You must specify a value for this required field." It showed after validating from the server.

SharePoint 
 2013 shows a message:

> "You can't leave this blank."

after validating from the client. But, if you use SharePoint webpart and SharePoint control, it still shows a message same as SharePoint 2010. It makes it inconsistent from your site.

Comment: OP wants to show different messages for each of the fields, not change it everywhere